# Error parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded with Unicode post data

Tags: java, post, playframework, playframework-2.0

Play refuses to accept a POST request when the data is unicode and I get:

> Error parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I was under the impression that everything is working great until I tried a request with text in Hebrew instead of English, so a request with

```
value=hey
```

works fine but a request with

```
value=%u05D4%u05D9%u05D9
```

fails.

I found [something about it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/-rf3Y3h5MJA/61HRSW2ewQoJ) but he said he made it worked by changing play/api/mvc/ContentType.scala, something I'd like to avoid.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

---

## Edit

I'm aware that the encoding does not fit the standards for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but that's the case I need to deal with, changing the client side currently is not an option and it uses the javascript `escape` method.

I'm looking for a solution on the backend side of things, that is a Play solution.
It would be nice to find a solution which can be implemented in java, but for now it looks like the solution is to write my own BodyParser (in scala).

Comment: I've never seen that particular kind of encoding - do you have a reference suggesting it should work?

Comment: We're working with an older system we have, and this specific error is happening when Play is proxying it. It uses Flask and there are no problems on that end, flask accepts this encoding. What I wrote there is "hey" in hebrew after escaping it: `escape("היי")`

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. One thing supporting it doesn't mean that it's a standard way of doing things...

Comment: Well, it's a common practice to escape strings before sending them to the server, since there's no other text manipulation other than that, I think it qualifies as a standard, no?

Comment: Yes, escaping is common practice - but I haven't seen the `%u` form or URL encoding before. That's why I asked for references for it. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding%5Fin%5Fa%5FURI) suggests that it would generally be better to use normal `%xx` encoding of the UTF-8 octet sequence.

Comment: In this case I have no way of changing how the data is sent, it's not my system (the client) that sends it.. I know it just escapes the text, which works with english but not with hebrew... Try it yourself, copy this: `escape("היי")` and run it in your chrome console and you'll get the output I posted.  But in general, it makes little sense to find a solution in the client side, I should have a way to handle "weird" encoding in the server side.. Is there a way to do so with Play?

Comment: Well it escapes it - but that doesn't mean it escapes it in a way which is suitable for x-www-form-urlencoded. If you try `encodeURI("היי")` instead, you get `"%D7%94%D7%99%D7%99"` which is more like what I'd expect to see. It sounds like the client is basically sending invalid data. I think it makes *perfect* sense to find a solution in the client side, if it's sending data which does not comply with the MIME type it's sending. (Just for the sake of interest, try sending that URI-encoded data to your Play server and see whether it gets the right result.)

Comment: As I said, changing the client won't be easy, we're using a framework which makes the requests, we will stop using it for various reasons, but for now I'm interested in a server side solution.  I don't mind that play can't deal with the encoding by default, but it should let me add support for other encoding and that's what I'm looking for. Any idea?

Comment: No, you'd have to start digging around in the Play Framework source code I suspect - changing how `x-www-form-urlencoded` data is decoded isn't the kind of thing you'd typically make configurable...

Comment: Your encoded string is not legal; %u is an illegal escape. Care to show the code you use to generate that string?

Comment: yeah, it's written in one of the comments, here it is again, very simple, open the developer tools of your browser, go to console and paste: `escape("היי")` and you'll get `%u05D4%u05D9%u05D9`

Comment: Kind of a shot in the dark here, but perhaps you could write your own BodyParser for use with the request in question? (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaBodyParsers)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's my current plan..  It's just that I have no scala experience and it can only be done with scala, and so I was looking for an easier solution for the java users of play... As it seems that the answer is no, I'm currently looking into the whole scala and BodyParsers solution. thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, the correct way to handle Unicode in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body is to translate the Unicode to bytes in the document's default charset (i.e. UTF-8) and then URL-encode the bytes (i.e. %-encode).

Certainly what you are currently doing (with '%uxxxx' sequences) is not a valid encoding as far as the specifications are concerned.  (You can't just pull stuff out of the air like that ... and expect it to work.)

References:

- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type
- HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm .  This gives the algorithm that a browser is supposed to use.  If you do / produce something analogous, you should be fine.

---

I note that you discovered this escape syntax via your browser's console.   Here's what the MSDN says about the Javascript `escape()` method:

> *"The escape and unescape functions do not work properly for non-ASCII characters and have been deprecated. In JavaScript 1.5 and later, use encodeURI, decodeURI, encodeURIComponent, and decodeURIComponent."*

I think that *"do not work properly"* means that they use a non-standard escaping syntax that browsers don't recognize.  Lesson: read the spec rather than relying on experiments.

Comment: Yeah, while `escape` is deprecated and should not be used, I currently have no way of changing that since it comes from the client and I can't change it. Since we were using a different backend (flask) before play, and it worked on that, switching to play kind of broke the service..  What I'm looking for is how to deal with it on the play side of things, and looks like I'll have to implement my own BodyParser

Comment: @NitzanTomer - If you have to live within those constraints, you are probably right.  However, the fact that it worked before doesn't mean it was correct before.  Sending escape sequences that are not recognized by the standard is arguably broken behaviour, even if it "worked".  The point of standards is that everyone / everything should follow them.

Comment: I completely agree, it's just that the client side is currently not in our hands..  It may change in the future, but for now it's a 3rd party peace of software, and they are using `escape`.. So basically I'm searching for a solution that will let me deal with stupidity.

Comment: even better, we're just going to stop using them :)